# Web World Wide Data Mining

Tags: data-mining

I have been working on a project out of curiosity to get millions of URLs returned by search engines and save them to a text file or any other data source of mine.

with time my

I started my research by looking at Google Search API old one and new ones but they just returns you couple of hundred of URLs only, I also tried looking at different other search engines but couldn't find much.

Now since I am more curious I started looking at how search engine works, how they index million of websites, "web crawler" was the answer but am still looking for the best way to get  URLs of websites for a specific search query using web crawler might take me ages to get URLs I want.

Since this question is related to Data Mining so posting here, Would really appreciate if someone guide me in right direction please.

**what I actual need is "Millions of URLs for a specific query" e.g. all websites returned for "Apple"**

I don't mind reading books at all, and also if you can state that working on such kind of projects can help me in any type of career.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Inspite of the fact that you are mining for URLs I don't think this question fits this site.

Comment: URLs comes as form of data and also I don't think there's any better SO or SE site for asking this question however answer I got below looks very informatic and I think it might help me for what I want achieve :)

Comment: Yes mining data but still off topic for the site.  Anyway you probablb got the answer you were looking for before we got enough votes to close.  So no worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering here because I don't have enough rep points for a comment. If you're interested in building solution, I wrote a blog that explores [SQLLite vs Mongo](http://www.os-scientific.org/2011/11/sqlite-vs-mongo/) for the data storage. The code (in Python) is on [GitHub](https://github.com/drjerry/webcrawler).

Apologies for the self promotion. There are surely many other -- and better -- code bases out there for you to start from if you want to take this route.

Comment: cheers, I will try it over weekend and see if it helps :)